# Push index of characters in Array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexof

I'm just playing around with Javascipt as an exercise. I just want to push the index number of every space in my string, into an array. No luck though, my array is coming up empty - or full of spaces, I'm not sure which. Any help would be gracefully received. :)

```js
function checkText() {
 var str1 = document.getElementById("texty").innerHTML;
 var dexArray = [];
 
 for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
  if (str1.indexOf(str1[i]) === " ") {
    dexArray.push(str1.indexOf(str1[i]));
   }
 }
 alert(dexArray);
}
```

```html
<p id="texty">Mary had a little lamb</p>
<button onclick="checkText()">Click</button>
```

Comment: infexOf will return a number. `-1` for non matching and index of others but never `" "`

Comment: indexOf returns a number, will never be equal to an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only the check against the character at position `i` and push it to the result if found.

```js
function checkText() {
    var str1 = document.getElementById("texty").innerHTML;
    var dexArray = [];
 
    for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        if (str1[i] === " ") {
            dexArray.push(i);
        }
    }
    console.log(dexArray);
}
```

```html
<p id="texty">Mary had a little lamb</p>
<button onclick="checkText()">Click</button>
```

A version with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```js
function checkText() {
    var str1 = document.getElementById("texty").innerHTML,
        dexArray = [],
        i = str1.indexOf(' ');
 
    while (i !== -1) {
        dexArray.push(i);
        i = str1.indexOf(' ', i + 1); // change start postion for search
    }
    console.log(dexArray);
}
```

```html
<p id="texty">Mary had a little lamb</p>
<button onclick="checkText()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of your `if-condition`, `indexOf` returns a `number` instead of a `string` let alone a empty space character `' '`.

```js
function checkText() {
 var str1 = document.getElementById("texty").innerHTML;
 var dexArray = [];
 
 for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    str1.charAt(i) == ' ' && dexArray.push(i);
 }
 alert(dexArray);
}
```

```html
<p id="texty">Mary had a little lamb</p>
<button onclick="checkText()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use comparison operator `==` or `===` instead `indexOf`

#### ES6 version

```js
function checkText() {
  var str1 = document.getElementById("texty").innerHTML;
  var dexArray = [];
  Array.from(str1).forEach((x,i)=>{x === " " && dexArray.push(i) });
  console.log(dexArray);
}
```

```html
<p id="texty">Mary had a little lamb</p>
<button onclick="checkText()">Click</button>
```

#### ES5 version

```js
function checkText() {
  var str1 = document.getElementById("texty").innerHTML;
  var dexArray = [];
  str1.split("").forEach(function(x,i){
    x === " " && dexArray.push(i) 
  });
  console.log(dexArray);
}
```

```html
<p id="texty">Mary had a little lamb</p>
<button onclick="checkText()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.indexOf` returns index of the given substring and you are comparing it to the space `'  '`. The whole use of `indexOf` is pointless. If you really *need* to use `indexOf` then you might want to look at the arguments this method takes and notoce that it can take an offset as the second parameter, but I always prefer the easier solution if I have one.

You can do something like this:

```
var str1 = 'whatever string you want to play with';
var arraySpaces = [];
var length = str1.length;
var i = -1;

while (++i < length) {
    if (str1[i] === ' ') {
        arraySpaces.push(i);
    }
}

console.log(arraySpaces);
```

This way you have the actual indexes of spaces in your array.

Since this is an exercise you might want to check out Regexp.prototype.test and Regexp's lastIndex which allows for more convenient index searches if you have some longer substring to look for.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

is  coming up empty,you can use alert("1"+dexArray+"1") test,because str1.indexOf(str1[i]) return number。